# How can Ivy be configured to create a conflict between different Oracle drivers?

Tags: oracle, ivy

I see projects that sometimes end up with both of the following in their resolved dependencies:

```
org="com.oracle" name="ojdbc14"
org="com.oracle" name="ojdbc6"
```

Because the version number is essentially part of the name, the normal conflict resolution methods don't detect or resolve this.

Can Ivy be configured to handle this? Even just breaking the build would be fine.

(Changing the name isn't an option at this point. I'm looking for something other than simply manually excluding one of them.)

Comment: how do you retrieve them in the first place? don't they have a version number in your repository?

Comment: They both have version numbers, I left that out because it doesn't seem relevant. The problem is the JRE-compatibility-version in their names: "14" and "6". It doesn't make sense to have both on the classpath at the same time. But Ivy thinks they are two different modules and doesn't have a problem with this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you'd prefer to ensure ivy only uses on of these JDBC jars and excludes the other?

In that case the simplest solution is a global level [exclude](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/exclude.html) statement in your ivy file:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency ..
   <dependency ..
   <dependency ..

   <exclude org="com.oracle" module="ojdbc14"/>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I know that's an option. I'm looking for something other than manually excluding one of them.

Comment: Well, as you correctly outlined in your question the conflict resolution functionality is normally applied to versions of the same module. Configurations is the only mechanism for grouping different modules together in ivy, loosely similar to Maven's scoping mechanism. Happen to have an example of a Maven module referencing both libaries? Perhaps it's possible to exclude one based on a configuration mapping.